# prove that a function $\psi$ does not change when arguments are permuted.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given a function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, consider

$$
\psi(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}) = \frac{(x_{3}-x_{2})f(x_{1}) + (x_{1}-x_{3})f(x_{2}) + (x_{2}-x_{1})f(x_{3})}{(x_{1}-x_{2})(x_{2}-x_{3})(x_{3}-x_{1})}
$$

The function $\psi(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3})$ does not change when the arguments $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$ are permuted.

Is there a clever way than enumerating all the 6 permutations of $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}$ and simplifying to prove that $\psi(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3})$ is invariant to permutations of its arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing it as: $$\sum_{cyc} \frac{f(x_1)}{(x_2-x_1)(x_3-x_1)}$$ shows the invariance to cyclical permutations, and since the denominator is symmetric in $x_2,x_3$ the expression is invariant to all permutations.